# Why doesn't iptables command take effect on my embeded Linux?

Tags: http, iptables, netstat

I'm running an embedded Linux system, whose kernel is 3.18.21,  with some applications on top it on MIPS. When I run iptables & ip6tables on the Linux, such as the following:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP 
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

The tcp port 80 is for http. Then I found that the http connection to this Linux server (there is a web server app running on the Linux server) doesn't work any longer.

But when I run netstat command as the following:

```
netstat -tuln | grep LISTEN
```

It shows the following (I only extract the port80):

```
tcp        0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Does this mean the port 80 is still open? Then why I can't use http to access the web server running on the Linux? (I checked and confirmed that the web server process is still running.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP

This restricts access from outside the machine, i.e. the port is no longer **open** for outside access.

> netstat -tuln | grep LISTEN

This checks if a **service is running**.

If a service is not running it does not matter much if the port is open for outside access since there is nothing behind the port. If the service is running but the port is not open for outside access, then it cannot be reached from outside but it can still be reached local from the machine.

> Then why I can't use http to access the web server running on the Linux

For a service to be accessible from outside,

- the service must be running in the first place
- the service must be listing on an IP address accessible from outside (i.e. not just on localhost 127.0.0.1 and ::1)
- the port must be open for access from outside, i.e. no firewall rules restricting access